# Getting median of an unsorted list with selection algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, search

I have a list of integers, and I want to use selection to find the median of this unsorted list. This is what I have so far, but I am not getting any output for my test list `[140, 240, 180, 400, 340]`. Can someone explain what needs to be done to get the median?

My code

```
def fastSelect(aList, k):

    count = 0
    pivot = 0
    smallerList = []
    largeList = []
    while aList != []:
        pivot == len(aList)//2
        for i in range(0,pivot):
            smallerList.append(aList[i])
        for j in range(pivot + 1,len(aList)):
            largeList.append(aList[j])
        for g in range(0,len(aList)):
            if aList[g] == pivot:
                count += 1
        m = len(smallerList)
        if k >= m and k < m + count:
            return pivot
        if m > k:
            aList = smallerList
        else:
            k = k - m - count
            aList = largeList
```

Comment: Why did you expect output? The indentation is off and you don't `return` anything.

Comment: Indentation is off from pulling it out of the IDE. sorry.

Comment: I should also say I do not fully understand selection and I am just trying something from what I have read online.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually comparing against your `pivot` value. You also have a bug that you're using `==` instead of `=` for assignment with your `pivot` initialization.

```
def fastSelect(aList, k):
    while aList:
        smallerList = []
        largeList = []
        count = 0
        pivot = aList[len(aList) // 2]
        for i in aList:
            if i < pivot:
                smallerList.append(i)
            elif i > pivot:
                largeList.append(i)
            else:
                count += 1
        m = len(smallerList)
        if k >= m and k < m + count:
            return pivot
        if m > k:
            aList = smallerList
        else:
            k = k - m - count
            aList = largeList
```

To understand why the `pivot` becomes the median, you need to think about what the definition of the median is. The median is a value in the list that is less than or equal to half of the other values and greater than or equal to half of the other values.

The first time through the loop, the middle value is chosen as the `pivot`. It then splits the list in to two lists: one that contains values that are smaller than the `pivot` and one that contains values that are larger than the `pivot`. Similarly a `count` of values equal to the `pivot` is maintained. Next, it sees how many values are in each list. If both lists are the same size or within the difference of `count` then by definition we've found the median, so we return the `pivot`.

So now we must maintain this invariant throughout the loop. Let's look at each of the cases. If the size of `smallerList` (which is represented as `m`) is larger than `k` then the median must be inside `smallerList`, and we're still looking for the `kth` element inside of `smallerList`. If `k` is greater than `m` then the median must be inside `largeList`, but we no longer need the `kth` element inside `largeList` because we've already found `m` and `count` elements that are smaller than or equal to the `pivot`, so we subtract those from `k` before continuing the loop.

Lastly, you could actually improve this code by using a random pivot. If you look at Wikipedia's article on the [Quickselect algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) you'll see that a random pivot guarantees almost certain linear time complexity whereas the middle position pivot that you've chosen has more predictable worst case analysis.